# Parse Factor in R

Tags: r, parsing

I have a column of ID data (class factor) in the following format: 01-001 etc.

I'd like to extract the first two digits (01) and create a separate column using these digits, ensuring they are numeric.

I did this a few years ago but can't find my old code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want `substr`:

```
substr(c("01-001", "12-121"), 0, 2)
# [1] "01" "12"
```

or perhaps

```
as.numeric(substr(c("01-001", "12-121"), 0, 2))
# [1]  1 12
```

Comment: Perfect, that got me going. Thanks Julius. I went with

dataframe$variable = substr(dataframe$variable, 0, 2)
dataframe$variable = as.numeric(dataframe$variable)